# Throwing an exception from a variable

Tags: java, exception

Using java, I want to do something like

```
try {
  someMethod();
} catch (Throwable x) {
  x.setMessage("Some comment " + x.getMessage());
  throw x;
}
```

That is, I do not know what "someMethod" will throw.  Whatever it is, I want to add a message at the beginning of its message, and then throw the error.  But Throwable does not have a setMessage() method.

I can do a `Class<? extends Throwable> cls = x.getClass();` to get the class type, but I am not sure of the syntax.  I can't do 
a `throw new cls("Comment " + x.getMessage());` I am sure there must be a fairly simple way to do this, when you don't know the class of the throwable that is thrown.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the more common pattern of `catch (Throwable t) { throw new CustomExceptionOrSomething("Some comment", e); }`?

Comment: It's not recommended to catch `Throwable`, since those could be JVM-level conditions (e.g., `OutOfMemoryError`). In almost all cases, you'd be better off catching `Exception` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply catch the `Exception` thrown by `someMethod()` and then re-throw it with the message you want.

Something like,

```
try {
   someMethod();
} catch(Exception ex) {
   /* Optional: Log Error */
   Logger.error(..., ex);
   throw new Exception("Error Occurred While Processing Request.", ex);
}
```

If you want you can also create and throw a checked exception as follows,

**CustomException Class:**

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {
    /* Optional: Add Serial UID */

    public CustomException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public CustomException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

**Code:**

```
try {
   someMethod();
} catch(Exception ex) {
   /* Optional: Log Error */
   Logger.error(..., ex);
   throw new CustomException("Error Occurred While Processing Request.", ex);
}
```

Comment: I think I will try user2004685's suggestion since I can then add the exception to the array

Answer (score 2):

Instead of catching `Throwable` (which is almost *always* a mistake), you can create a custom `RuntimeException` and wrap your caught exception in that.

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {
    public MyException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}

try {
    someMethod();
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new MyException("A major error has occurred!", e);
}
```

Comment: Or just wrap it directly in a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Actually it occurs to me I need them to be assertion errors because I want the test (this is with Selenium) to continue even if a specific part fails.  I have a List<AssertionError> errors = new ArrayList<>() to which I will add each error thrown and then throwIfNecessary() at the end

Comment: I will supplement the answer above, that you can also create your own custom exception, inheriting not only from RuntimeException but also from Exception class